# Date Query Syntax

Tags: solr

I have a index in Solr, and the requirement is that dates should be serchable in the format:

```
date:[20010101 TO 20011231]
```

Not ugly Solr, DateTime format.

Any idea how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

With [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HttpDataSource_Example) you can check for

```
<field column="date_format" name="date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

And you can check if you can range query on this date field.

If normal indexing, you would need to probably convert the Query date into the format required by Solr

Comment: I did as u said, but it throws an error in my face  `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Schema Parsing Failed: Invalid field prope
rty: dateTimeFormat`. I tried also all letters small, same error... Any idea why?

Comment: with Solrj, but why does it matter? it throws an error when I try to create sharded collection

Comment: My bad. Its with DIH Only. So you would need to handle the conversion at client before querying Solr.

Comment: Do u know where exactly in DIH they use it, so I can check the example, pls?

Comment: i have provided a link in the answer you can check.

Comment: well, thats something different. If I understand it correctly, it is data import handler configuration of inputs

Comment: yup its different. You would need to convert the user inputy data as per the Solr format to query Solr